# Solr DIH from MySQL with multiple collections

Tags: mysql, solr

I have a question about the Solr Data Import Handler. I'm using Solr 5.2.1 on a Linux server with 32G ram.

I have five different collections, and for each collection, I'm trying to import data from a different MySQL database. All of the MySQL queries work properly in MySQL, and previously I was able to use all of these queries building an index with LucidWorks Search 2.9 (Solr 4.7).

The problem is that when starting Solr it will not finish starting, but does not give an error, and the admin GUI does not show. But if I try to start with only one collection, it works okay.

I am assuming that the problem has to do either with my incorrect execution of the data-config files, or use of the unique IDs.

Here is what I have.

In the data config files (examples here, all other data config files are similar, and use the same name)

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Books" user="myuser" password="12345" />
    <document>
        <entity name="book_list" query="SELECT book_id, book_title, book_date FROM book_list WHERE book_date > '2015-01-01'" >
             <field column="book_id" name="id" />
             <field column="book_title" name="title" />
             <field column="book_date" name="book_date_solr" />
            <entity name="book_author" query="SELECT book_author.full_name, book_author.full_name_solr FROM book_author LEFT JOIN book_list ON book_author.book_id = book_list.book_id WHERE book_list.book_id = ${book_list.book_id}" >
                <field column="full_name" name="full_name" />
                <field column="full_name_solr" name="full_name_solr" />
            </entity>
            <entity name="book_type" query="SELECT book_type.publication_type FROM book_type LEFT JOIN book_list ON book_type.book_id = book_list.book_id WHERE book_list.book_id = ${book_list.book_id}" >
                <field column="publication_type" name="publication_type" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
     </document>
</dataConfig>
```

In schema.xml file (I use the same schema.xml for each collection)

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
<field name="book_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" required="false" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

(all fields from the data config files are added, but I'm not showing here for the sake of brevity)

When Solr is starting, this is as far as it goes:

```
INFO  - org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig; Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; Reading Solr Schema from /usr/lib/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/Books/conf/schema.xml
INFO  - org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig; Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; Reading Solr Schema from /usr/lib/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/BookStores/conf/schema.xml
INFO  - org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig; Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; Reading Solr Schema from /usr/lib/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/BookSales/conf/schema.xml
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; [Books] Schema name=Schema521
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; [BookStores] Schema name= Schema521
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; [BookSales] Schema name= Schema521
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; unique key field: id
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; unique key field: id
INFO  - org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema; unique key field: id
```

I've tried many different alternatives in the above dataconfig, such as in the query select:

```
book_id AS id
book_id AS 'id'
```

and adding `pk="book_id"` to the entity.

Also I tried to change all of the IDs and make them unique in each schema like `<uniqueKey>book_id</uniqueKey>`, but that did not work.

While I'm trying to fix this problem, I am wondering if Solr requires that the unique key for every collection must be " id ", or can it be any name, such as "book_id"?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Solr does not need the unique key field taking the name "id"; it just has to be declared as you did. If you change the name, you must reindex the core. Do all of you imports write into the same core, or du you have five cores?

Comment: Thanks. I have five different cores (collections). I've been using the same solrconfig and schema for each collection. For simplicity, I normalised the ID so I would not need to make different schema/config files for each collection (but the information in the data config is or course different for each, but has the same name).

Comment: The two missing cores start up when you leave out the others? And you update them (all) on startup? Maybe you exceed some connection limit on the database?

Comment: The solution was to delete the transaction log (tlog) in one of the cores. Although it was not very big, it seemed to be caught-up on a previous indexing error and that kept trying to load. The suggestion was made by Erick Erickson at the Solr Forum.